# How to access array item by property value and then update it's value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of object that looks like this:

```
const tickets = 
[
  {
    ticketId: 'aaa',
    authorId: 'abc',
    replyCount: 0,
    status: 'Open',
    threads: [
      {
        threadId: 'abc',
        authorId: 'abc',
        direction: 'in',
        content: 'blah blah blahh'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    ticketId: 'bbb',
    authorId: 'efg',
    replyCount: 0,
    status: 'Open',
    threads: [
      {
        threadId: 'efg',
        authorId: 'efg',
        direction: 'in',
        content: 'blah blah blahh'
      },
    ],
  },
  .......
]
```

Now I want to access the array item where `ticketId` equals `aaa` and change it's `threads` property.

I have tried doing using `tickets['aaa'].threads = [ ... ]` but it throws these errors:

Eslint: `Unsafe member access .threads on an 'any' value`

TypeScript: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'`

Comment: With tickets['aaa'] you are accessing the aaa property not the tickedId property. What you want to do is to filter all tickets where ticketId === 'aaa' thats completly different

Comment: Well, `tickets` doesn't have an `aaa` key. Its first element, an object, does, however.

Comment: Also, what do you want to do with `threads`? Do you want to replace it? Do you want to add a new object to it? Do you want to change the values of objects in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index where `ticketId` equals "aaa"

```js
tickets[tickets.findIndex(v => v.ticketId === "aaa")].threads = [/* ... */];
```

With index validation:

```js
const idx = tickets.findIndex(v => v.ticketId === "aaa");
if (idx > -1) tickets[idx].threads = [/* ... */];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wanna mutate by property you can get the index with indexOf and mutate

```
tickets[tickets.findIndex(ticket => ticket.ticketId === "aaa")].threads = [] //mutate here however you want
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` does not take a callback as an argument see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: You are right, it'd be ```findIndex```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following is useful for you.

```
var getItem = id => tickets.find(item => item.ticketId === id);

getItem("aaa"); // {ticketId: 'aaa', authorId: 'abc', replyCount: 0, status: 'Open', threads: Array(1)}
```

Comment: OP wanted to update `threads` this retrieves a copy of an item